# What is the board game in ‘Friends’ S05E11?

Tags: identify-this-game

Does anyone know the name of the board game visible on the following picture?
[image: Still from Friends S05E11]
The image is taken from the eleventh episode of the fifth season of *Friends* ("The One With All The Resolutions"), at around 4/5 of the episode (17:53 is the exact timestamp of the frame from my version).

The things I thought might help to identify the game:

- The game seems to have an oval board.
- There are two small blue UFO-shaped parts (*maybe dice poppers?*): one on the table and one in the hands of Joey (second guy from the left).
- There seems to be two different kind of cards involved - in red and blue colors.
- The box features a cartoonish drawing of a woman and a man and the dominant color seems purple.
- The game seems to support 5 players - but considering it's a tv show, this might not hold true. I recon yellow, red and blue figures on the board, and it seems that there are two from each color.

Comment: You mention coloured pieces on the board.  There also appear to be two white pieces off the board as well.  When I zoom in on the board the pawns appear 'wine bottle' shaped but that is not clear.

Comment: @StartPlayer The white pieces I think are just the caps of the water bottles, but I may be wrong. But yep, the figures seems 'wine bottle' shaped.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is [Men Are from Mars, Women Are from Venus](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3515/men-are-mars-women-are-venus). You can recognise the loopy indigo board, the characters on the box, and the red/green card box in this image from the BoardGameGeek page:

[image: an oval-shaped colorful board, a box with a man and a woman on it, and a box of cards with red and green sections]